# Is this some form of encrypted data?

Tags: algorithm, base64, encryption, decode

Is this some kind of encrypted text. If so what is the message? What algorithm do they use to encrypt it.

> /wEPDwUKLTg4NzIyNzcwNw9kFgICAw9kFggCAw8PFgIeBFRleHQFD1N1Z2FuIEtyaXNobmFuIWRkAgUPDxYCHwAFATVkZAIHDw8WAh4ISW1hZ2VVcmwFEX4vaW1hZ2VzL0ZpdmUuanBnZGQCDQ8PFgQfAAUOVHJ5IG9uY2UgbW9yZSEeB1Zpc2libGVnZGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFDEltYWdlQnV0dG9uMbKoXKekKw34NtoM3F7LSsVyk27i

and this one also

> /wEWAwKF0NmYAwLs0bLrBgLSwpnTCAezV8kYXyYZ4dulPyQ9ezcN3auX

Comment: With my answer, you can have a bash at decoding the second one too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe; have you tried base64 decoding it, etc?

EDIT: yep, or something close to, as it's not *all* human readable -- if you let us know the context in which you acquired it, someone might be able to guess the format. Otherwise, we'll be making all sorts of guesses.

ÿ
-887227707ddTextSugan Krishnan!dd5ddImageUrl~/images/Five.jpgdd
Try once more!Visiblegdd_*ControlsRequirePostBackKey*_ImageButton1²¨\§¤+
ø6ÚÜ^ËJÅr“nâ

(Thanks to this [online Base64 decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)).

Comment: Sounds like it comes from Wikileaks

Comment: Extra points If you can explain when and why :) (good so question?)